# What is wrong with this downforce calculcation?

Tags: forces, aerodynamics, drag

I tried calculating the downforce of a [spoiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoiler_%28automotive%29) I need for a robot. I used this formula.

$$F = \frac{1}{2}Ac_a\rho v^2$$

Where $\rho$ is air density, $v$ is the speed of my robot, $c_a$ is the lift coefficient and $A$ is the windage of the spoiler which I calculate by multiplying its width, length and angle of attack in radians.

$$A = w l \sin(\alpha\frac{\pi}{180})$$

I used the following values for calculation.

$w = 0.07m, l = 0.04m, \alpha=45^°$

$c_a =1$, because I don't know a better approximation.

$\rho = 1.2041\frac{kg}{m^3}$

$v = 3.5\frac{m}{s}$

And I got as result, that the downforce is around 0,0146 Newton which seems a lot too small. What is wrong with my calculation, or is it actually correct? (I need to compensate about 50N in small turns.)

Comment: You are considering the speed of the air passing below the spoiler equal to zero. Is this true? Also, I honestly don't know if you can consider the speed of the air passing above equal to the speed of the robot.

Comment: Your spoiler is 4x7 cm, traveling at a rate of 12.6 km/h, and you want a downward force of 5kg? On top of that, the angle is 45 degrees, more than twice the stall angle of attack?

Comment: @cinico There will be air passing below the spoiler, I think with around the speed of the robot. Thanks for pointing that out. How can I consider that in the formula? Shouldn't the air passing above the robot be nearly equal to the speed of the robot? There is no external wind involved.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey I know that I cannot get the 50N easily, but aren't 0,0146N a bit too small? Is there an optimal angle of attack for a spoiler?

Comment: @danijar The force produced on the spoiler will be a result of a pressure difference (above is higher than below). A difference of pressure will create a force in a certain certain area of the material. Roughly, what you should change in your equation is the v^2. It should be (v_below - v_above)^2 , where v_below is the velocity of the air passing below and v_above above the spoiler. I'd risk to say that that value is not too far from the true. It is probably pointless to use a spoiler with that size and velocity.

Comment: @cinico So the truly hard part about calculating the downforce is how find out how fast the air is passing above and below the spoiler, right? How can I estimate that?

Comment: @danijar Though I'm not even close of being an expert in aerodynamics, I believe that's not a trivial thing to do. I think you have two choices - "experience and measure" or "computer simulation". Maybe this is good software to start http://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/k-12/FoilSim/

Comment: @cinico Thanks. I cannot experience and measure at the moment because I want a proof of concept before constructing the actual robot and only do a bit tweaking of the spoiler then. I'm going to check out the software though. If you want to write an answer from the last comments, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: First, [*do some learning about wings*](http://www.av8n.com/how/htm/aoa.html), because 19 degrees is about the largest angle of attack possible without stalling. Second, *experiment*. You say you cannot experience and measure, but yes, you can.

Comment: I highly doubt you want to run your spoiler at 45 degrees. Airplane wings rarely operate above an $\alpha$ of 15 degrees, most wings stall by 12 degrees. The coefficient of lift can hardly be assumed to 1. It varies from well under 1 to well above 1 in some cases. Additionally, you design the wing (dimensions, airfoil, etc) taking into account the lift you need to generate, not the other way around.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi You comment was very helpful for me, thanks.